# Filter alphanumeric strings in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have already checked related questions and tried the solutions there, but none of them are working.

I have a column where I need to filter every alphanumeric string, it doesn't matter the pattern, as long as it finds both a letter and a number, it needs to be filtered out.
I already tried using the regex `^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$`, `[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]` (using double negative) but I'm still getting a bunch of alphanumeric strings in my output.

The last query I used was

```
SELECT distinct ID
FROM TABLE
where ID like '^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$' and ID is not null
```

I already played around inverting the `like` but to no avail, it still outputs alphanumeric strings.
This is using Snowflake, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want regular expressions, use `regexp`:

```
where id regexp '^(?=[A-Za-z0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```

`like` is not for regular expressions but for SQL pattern matching.  Its only wildcards are `_` and `%`.

If you want both a letter and a number, then this might be simpler:

```
where id regexp '[a-zA-Z]' and id regexp '[0-9]'
```

Or as one expression:

```
where id regexp '([a-zA-Z].*[0-9])|([0-9].*[a-zA-Z])'
```

If you want only letters and numbers:

```
where id not regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

Comment: I used the last one with not regexp '([a-zA-Z].*[0-9])|([0-9].*[a-zA-Z])' and its still returning alphanumeric. And the first option is returning error "no argument for repetition operator"

Comment: @Elmambo2194 . . . It is unclear what you are looking for, because your question does not provide a clear explanation with sample data and desired results.  This answer addresses how you use regular expressions in Snowflake.

Comment: Its a column containing customers IDs. We are changing the format in which we make these IDs from an old alphanumeric format to a new numeric one, so we need to count how many IDs currently have the numeric format.

Therefore, we need to make a count of distinct IDs, where the IDs are completely numerical (so not alphanumeric)